# Reverse ACF Flexible content Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I'am working with advanced custom fields flexible content and I wonder how to reverse this loop in php so latest article is on the top. Just like posts in wordpress. Thank you!

```
<?php if( have_rows('article_content') ): ?>
    <?php while( have_rows('article_content') ): the_row(); ?>

        <?php if( get_row_layout() == 'article') : ?>

            <a href="<?php the_sub_field('link'); ?>" class="article">
                <?php $att = get_sub_field('image');?>
                <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $att, 'article-crop' ); ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>">
                <h3><?php the_sub_field('title'); ?></h3>
            </a>

        <?php elseif( get_row_layout() == 'html' ): ?>
              <?php the_sub_field('html_code'); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I can't see any post that will be displayed with this code ? It's only custom fields without posts relation.

Comment: Hey Alexis, yes there is no posts. It's just acf flexible content that I want to revere it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two solutions i can think of.

1. Store `get_field('article_content')` on an array, reverse it and display the rows by accessing data in the array instead of using ACF Functions.
2. Use `ob_start()`, `ob_get_contents()`, `ob_end_clean()` to store the html of each rows in an array and reverse it. I prefer this solution because you can use ACF Functions.

I adapted your code with the second solution :

```
  <?php 
 $rows_array = array();
 if( have_rows('article_content') ): ?>
        <?php while( have_rows('article_content') ): the_row(); 
          ob_start();
        ?>

        <?php if( get_row_layout() == 'article') : ?>

            <a href="<?php the_sub_field('link'); ?>" class="article">
                <?php $att = get_sub_field('image');?>
                <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $att, 'article-crop' ); ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>">
                <h3><?php the_sub_field('title'); ?></h3>
            </a>

        <?php elseif( get_row_layout() == 'html' ): ?>
              <?php the_sub_field('html_code'); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php 
       $rows_array[] = ob_get_contents();
       ob_end_clean(); 
       endwhile; 
    ?>
 <?php 
   $rows_reversed_array = array_reverse($rows_array);
   echo implode('', $rows_reversed_array);
 ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Code not tested but i'm pretty sure it should work.

You also can replace :

```
$rows_array[] = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

by

```
$rows_array[] = ob_get_clean();
```

It's a shorter way to do the same thing.